Add Footer to PDF using Python via Acrobat COM Interface (AddWatermarkFromText)
EDIT: I've figured out the solution, see my reply below.
Original Post:
I can add a footer via VBA with this code:
Dim PDDocDestination As Object
Dim JSO As Object
Dim i As Long, numPages As Long

Set PDDocDestination = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")

Set JSO = PDDocDestination.GetJSObject
numPages = PDDocDestination.GetNumPages

' Loop through each page and add the footer
For i = 1 To numPages
    JSO.addWatermarkFromText cText:="text", cFont:="CenturyGothic", nFontSize:=7, nHorizAlign:=1, nVertAlign:=4, nVertValue:=12.5, nStart:=i - 1, nEnd:=i - 1
Next i

'Save destination (merged) PDF
PDDocDestination.Save PDSaveFull, mergedPDF
PDDocDestination.Close

'Cleanup
Set PDDocDestination = Nothing
Set JSO = Nothing

However, when I try to translate this to Python, I get the following error on the AddWatermarkFromText method: pywintypes.com_error: (-2147467263, 'Not implemented', None, None). I've tried every permutation I can think of. Here's my code:
def add_footer_to_pdf(pdf_path, output_path, text, font="CenturyGothic", font_size=7, horiz_align=1, vert_align=4, vert_value=12.5):
    # Create COM object to interact with Acrobat
    try:
        AcroApp = Dispatch("AcroExch.App")
        AcroPDDoc = Dispatch("AcroExch.PDDoc")
        AcroPDDoc.Open(pdf_path)
        JSO = AcroPDDoc.GetJSObject()
        num_pages = AcroPDDoc.GetNumPages()

        # Loop through each page and add the footer
        for i in range(num_pages):
            JSO.addWatermarkFromText(cText=f"{text}, page {i+1}", cFont=font, nFontSize=font_size, nHorizAlign=horiz_align, nVertAlign=vert_align, nVertValue=vert_value, nStart=i, nEnd=i)

        # Save the modified PDF
        AcroPDDoc.Save(1, output_path)
        # if not AcroPDDoc.Save(1, output_path):
        #     print("Failed to save the PDF")
    finally:
        AcroPDDoc.Close()
        AcroApp.Exit()
        del AcroApp, AcroPDDoc

I don't know if that's because the method just isn't available via pywin32/win32com, but I assume that since it's available in VBA, it should be available in Python. I worried that the PDDoc object wasn't initialized properly or the document wasn't opened correctly, but as far as I can tell, both seem to be fine; I get the correct number of pages with AcroPDDoc.GetNumPages().
I've tried calling addWatermarkFromText with and without parameters, with and without parentheses, even with an upper and lowercase 'A'.
Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

To fix JSObject not working, import Dispatch from win32com.client.dynamic (instead of win32com.client) and add winerror.E_NOTIMPL to the ERRORS_BAD_CONTEXT list in dynamic.py.
ERRORS_BAD_CONTEXT = [
    winerror.DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND,
    winerror.DISP_E_BADPARAMCOUNT,
    winerror.DISP_E_PARAMNOTOPTIONAL,
    winerror.DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH,
    winerror.E_INVALIDARG,
    winerror.E_NOTIMPL,
]

The solution was posted here by Subhobroto. Amazing!
I will also add that when using addWatermarkFromText(), you can't use keyword arguments, so you need to include every parameter up until the last one you need. Annoying, but at least they follow the order provided by Adobe in the SDK:

Unfortunately, I don't believe you can use the constants (at least I don't know of a way).
For the font, I was able to just use the name of the font file (ttf), i.e. "CenturyGothic".
For color you need to do use the code under Equivalent JavaScript (e.g., ["G", 0] for black or ["RGB", 1,0,0] for red).
All the rest are either True or False (as indicated in the SDK) or a number. For instance, the options for nHorizAlign are 0, 1 and 2, corresponding to left, center, and right. nVertAlign makes less sense, since 0, 1, and 2 all equal center, 3 is top, and 4 is bottom.
My footer function now looks like this, easily adaptable to your needs:
from win32com.client.dynamic import Dispatch

def add_footer_to_pdf(
    pdf_path,
    output_path,
    cText,
    nTextAlign=0,
    cFont="CenturyGothic",
    nFontSize=7,
    aColor=["G", 0],
    bOnTop=True,
    bOnScreen=True,
    bOnPrint=True,
    nHorizAlign=1,
    nVertAlign=4,
    nHorizValue=0,
    nVertValue=10,
    bPercentage=False,
    nScale=1.0,
    bFixedPrint=False,
    nRotation=0,
    nOpacity=1.0,
):

    # Create COM object to interact with Acrobat
    try:
        AcroApp = Dispatch("AcroExch.App")
        AcroPDDoc = Dispatch("AcroExch.PDDoc")
        if AcroPDDoc.Open(pdf_path):
            JSO = AcroPDDoc.GetJSObject()
            num_pages = AcroPDDoc.GetNumPages()

            # Loop through each page and add the footer
            for i in range(num_pages):
                JSO.addWatermarkFromText(
                    f"{cText}, page {i + 1}",
                    nTextAlign,
                    cFont,
                    nFontSize,
                    aColor,
                    i,
                    i,
                    bOnTop,
                    bOnScreen,
                    bOnPrint,
                    nHorizAlign,
                    nVertAlign,
                    nHorizValue,
                    nVertValue,
                    bPercentage,
                    nScale,
                    bFixedPrint,
                    nRotation,
                    nOpacity,
                )

            # Save the modified PDF
            AcroPDDoc.Save(1, output_path)
            if not AcroPDDoc.Save(1, output_path):
                print("Failed to save the PDF")
    finally:
        AcroPDDoc.Close()
        AcroApp.Exit()
        del AcroApp, AcroPDDoc

Instead of pdf_path and output_path, you could also make AcroPDDoc a parameter, import the PDDoc object and save/clean up outside the function:
def add_footer_to_pdf(
    AcroPDDoc,
    cText,
    nTextAlign=0,
    cFont="CenturyGothic",
    nFontSize=7,
    aColor=["G", 0],
    bOnTop=True,
    bOnScreen=True,
    bOnPrint=True,
    nHorizAlign=1,
    nVertAlign=4,
    nHorizValue=0,
    nVertValue=10,
    bPercentage=False,
    nScale=1.0,
    bFixedPrint=False,
    nRotation=0,
    nOpacity=1.0,
):

    JSO = AcroPDDoc.GetJSObject()
    num_pages = AcroPDDoc.GetNumPages()

    # Loop through each page and add the footer
    for i in range(num_pages):
        JSO.addWatermarkFromText(
            f"{cText}, page {i + 1}",
            nTextAlign,
            cFont,
            nFontSize,
            aColor,
            i,
            i,
            bOnTop,
            bOnScreen,
            bOnPrint,
            nHorizAlign,
            nVertAlign,
            nHorizValue,
            nVertValue,
            bPercentage,
            nScale,
            bFixedPrint,
            nRotation,
            nOpacity,
        )

